# How to force a python object to be of some specific other type for isinstance?

Tags: python, python-2.7

Assume

```
class A(object):
    def init(self):
        pass
```

and

```
o = object()
```

I want to force o to be of type `A` such that

```
isinstance(o, A) == True
```

is truthy.

Can this be done?

Note i am interested in both 2.7 and 3+ solutions.

Comment: Why don't you set `o = A()` instead?

Comment: because my data comes from a raw json format, which I parse into an object field by field. I also have a field stating which type the data is, but I don't want to add a constructor from_json for every possible type.

Comment: How do you set arbitrary attributes on an `object` instance? And you don't need to add a `from_json`. You can just do `o = A()` and use generic code to set the fields.

Answer (score 0):

You need to change the class of your object. This is not usually recommendend, as the documentation points out:

> It is possible in some cases to change an object’s type, under certain controlled conditions. It generally isn’t a good idea though, since it can lead to some very strange behaviour if it is handled incorrectly

If you had to "upcast" objects (upcast doesn't exist in Python) using two classes that you created

```
class A:
    pass

class B(A):
    pass
```

it would be easy to do what you're asking for:

```
a = A()
isinstance(a, B) # False
a.__class__ = B
isinstance(a, B) # True
```

However, this *can't* work with objects of type `object`. The documentation clearly says that

> object does not have a `__dict__`, so you can’t assign arbitrary attributes to an instance of the object class.

where `__dict__` is a dictionary or other mapping object used to store an object’s **writable** attributes.

Indeed:

```
o = object()
o.__class__ = A
# __class__ assignment only supported for heap types or ModuleType subclasses
```